# Update scope value across two instances of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an aside which will be displayed as a pop-up modal. The user will be able to interact with the modal and choose one of either two options.
If the user chooses to reject the offer I would simply like to hide the pop up modal and the overlay. 
I can hide the modal - the ng-show works perfectly fine. However, the overlay(which is a separate element, sitting in a separate part in the codebase) does not respect the updated scope value even though they are using the same directive and the value is coming from a singleton. How do I make sure that they are both in sync? 

Here's the modal

```
    <aside data-ng-show="!customerRejectedOffer" data-pi-browser-update class="md-modal md-show pi-modal-message modal-effect-2">
<div class="pi-modal-content">
    <h4>Title</h4>
                <div>
                    <p>Copy</p>
                    <ul class="flush--left nav--no-style-type">
                        <li>
                        <button class="pi-modal-content-button wb-btn wb-btn--secondary">
                            <a class="pi-modal-content-link" href="#" title="Upgrade Button">
                            <admin:keyvalues key="datedbrowser.iebutton"/></a>  
                        </button>
                        </li>
                        <li><button class="pi-modal-content-button pi-modal-content-button__refusal" data-ng-click="rejectOffer()"><a class="pi-modal-content-link" title=""></a></button></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button data-ng-click="rejectOffer()" class="pi-modal-content-close md-close">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</aside>
```

To manage the show/hide values as well as to handle the click event I have set up a directive.

```
(function() {

  'use strict';


  angular
    .module('pi.common.browserupdateMessage', ['pi.common.storage'])
    .directive('piBrowserUpdate', browserUpdate);

  function browserUpdate(SharedScopeUtility) {

    return {
      link: browserUpdateLink
    };

    function browserUpdateLink(scope) {
      scope.customerRejectedOffer = SharedScopeUtility.hasAcceptedUpgrade;
      console.log(scope);
      scope.customerRejectedOffer = customerRejectedOffer;

       function rejectOffer()() {
        SharedScopeUtility.hasAcceptedUpgrade = true;
        scope.customerRejectedOffer = SharedScopeUtility.hasAcceptedUpgrade;
      }

    }

  }

}());
```

As you can see in the directive, I am setting the initial value of `customerRejectedOffer` from a service I created called `SharedScopeUtility`.

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pi.app.sharedscopeutility', [
    'ngResource'
  ])

  .factory('SharedScopeUtility', function (){

    var hasAcceptedUpgrade = false;
    var _service = {
      hasAcceptedUpgrade: hasAcceptedUpgrade
    };

    return _service;
  });

}());
```

When the user clicks the "Rejected Offer Button" I fire off the `rejectOffer()` function which you can see in the directive. 
This function updates the value on the service from false to true and sets a new value on the scope called `customerRejectedOffer` which I then use in my ng-show. This works just fine for the pop-up modal. 
 However, the overlay element:

```
<div data-pi-browser-update data-ng-click="rejectOffer()" data-ng-show="!customerRejectedOffer" class="pi-modal-overlay"></div>
```

Which uses the exact same directive as well as value for it's ng-show **but** remains visible.
I created a service for this because I wanted the `rejectedOffer` boolean to come from a singleton, however that still doesn't give me any joy.
Help, please :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Most importantly, [Have a look at this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6xVMl9od6bd6Nog0l26?p=preview). The `data-ng-show` should listen directly to the `SharedScopeUtility.hasAcceptedUpgrade` service flag. Reference the `SharedScopeUtility` service on the scope - `scope.SharedScopeUtility = SharedScopeUtility`.
2. Your'e returning an empty function here - is it a mistake?:
   `function rejectOffer()()`
3. `rejectOffer()` should also be defined on the scope - `scope.rejectOffer = function(){}`
4. I've seen cases where directives needed a `$timeout` to propagate scope changes - but you can avoid that by referencing a service as suggested above.

Good luck and let me know if that helps!